# pandas to json, don't put double quotes on geometry field

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe with two fields coordinates and status

using pandas to_json, I get this

```
[{"coordinates":"[143.4865219,-34.7560602]","status":"not started"},
```

the correct format should be

```
[{"coordinates":[143.4865219,-34.7560602],"status":"not started"},
```

how to tell pandas not to put double quotes on the values of coordinates.

Comment: your `coordinates` field likely contains string objects, so pandas is correctly serializing it to a JSON string.

Comment: the file feed other system which require the the values of coordinates without double quotes.

Comment: yes, then don't use *strings* use *lists*, although, lists inside dataframes is generally a bad sign, but in any case, you need lists. the easies way is probably to use `ast.literal_eval` as suggested by the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try explicitly convert string list to list by using ast module
code

```
import ast
s = [{"coordinates":"[143.4865219,-34.7560602]","status":"not started"},{"coordinates":"[143.4865241,-34.7561332]","status":"not started"}]
s = list(map(lambda x : {"coordinates": ast.literal_eval(x['coordinates'].strip('"')), "status": x['status']}, s))
```

Comment: the status is fine,  I want only to remove double quotes from the values between []

Comment: then remove ast.literal_eval() method call.please accept the answer if it satisfy your requirement.

Comment: s = list(map(lambda x : {"coordinates": x['coordinates'].strip('"'), "status": x['status']}, s))

Comment: what is s, is it a dataframe

Comment: s = [{"coordinates":"[143.4865219,-34.7560602]","status":"not started"},{"coordinates":"[143.4865241,-34.7561332]","status":"not started"}] ,it's the output what you are getting from pandas to_json method

Comment: i get this error, TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: can you provide me your output and the data that you are getting from to_json method it seems like you are trying to put string in index place in lists

Comment: all good find the issue, the dataframe itself contain double quotes, PowerBI is a weird system, thank you very much